# Ensuring that string item is a valid string and not empty in Split?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method like this

```
public static List<string> ToList(this string str)
{
    return str.Split(',').ToList();
}
```

I want to know if I can keep the 1-line beauty and also check if the item in the split is actually a string without any whitespaces or a whitespace itself, so basically if its a solid word without and spaces.

Comment: ok. so if you check it....and its whitespace, then what? you can check that with linq...but ok...so what then? you have to either remove them or something, and that can be done w/linq too...you just have to add onto your 1 liner chain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How about this code block?**

```
public static List<string> ToList(this string str)
{
    return str.Split(',').Where(vstr => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vstr)).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Note - The above code has a distinct clause added, which will remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a `where` statement from LINQ.

```
public static List<string> ToList(this string str)
{
    return str.Split(',').Where( s=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
}
```